# GCM Notification isn't shown

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am implementing an Android App that sends a message to  PHP server then the PHP server that generates a GCM Push Notification directs it to the relevant Registration Ids. The problem is that the Notification isn't shown although the GCMIntentService class received the message as it is shown in the attached log cat

HERE is the Android code

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";
private static final String senderId = "*****";
String message;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(senderId);
}

static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("guc.edu.iremote.DISPLAY_MESSAGE");
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    // sets the app name in the intent
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderId);
    startService(registrationIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Your device registred with GCM");

}


@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    startService(unregIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
     displayMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Unregistered");

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    message = intent.getStringExtra( "message" );
     // message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

  Intent notificationIntent=new     Intent(context,this.getApplicationContext().getClass());
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |     PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
  wl.acquire();
  displayMessage(context, message);
 generateNotification(context, message, notificationIntent);

final AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
//Use an activity object here
 d.setMessage(message) //Provide a message here... A string or a string ID will do
 .setCancelable(false) //If you want them to be able to dismiss with a Back button
 .setPositiveButton(R.drawable.navigationaccept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {
     AlertDialog dialog = d.create();
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.dismiss();


    }
}) 

 .create()
 .show();


}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, Intent notificationIntent) {
     int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();


     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

     String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
  notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
 notification.ledOnMS = 300;
 notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
 }

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
     displayMessage(arg0, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);

}
}
```

AND here is the LOG CAT

```
11-22 22:49:10.747: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6305): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
11-22 22:49:10.747: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6305): GCM IntentService class:     guc.edu.iremote.GCMIntentService
11-22 22:49:10.747: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Acquiring wakelock

11-22 22:49:10.838: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Intent service name:       GCMIntentService-55975***5670-181

11-22 22:49:10.877: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): handleRegistration: registrationId = ****, error = null, unregistered = null
11-22 22:49:10.877: D/GCMRegistrar(6305): resetting backoff for guc.edu.iremote
11-22 22:49:10.907: V/GCMRegistrar(6305): Saving regId on app version 1
11-22 22:49:10.927: I/===GCMIntentService===(6305): Device registered: regId = ****
11-22 22:49:10.957: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Releasing wakelock

11-22 22:49:13.087: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6305): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
11-22 22:49:13.087: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6305): GCM IntentService class: guc.edu.iremote.GCMIntentService
11-22 22:49:13.087: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Acquiring wakelock

11-22 22:49:13.388: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-559753615670-182
11-22 22:49:13.388: I/Choreographer(6305): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-22 22:49:13.417: D/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): handleRegistration: registrationId = ****, error = null, unregistered = null
11-22 22:49:13.430: D/GCMRegistrar(6305): resetting backoff for guc.edu.iremote
11-22 22:49:13.430: V/GCMRegistrar(6305): Saving regId on app version 1

11-22 22:49:13.477: I/===GCMIntentService===(6305): Device registered: regId = ****
11-22 22:49:13.477: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6305): Releasing wakelock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code ...

```
 package com.gcm.demo;

    import static com.gcm.demo.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
    import static com.gcm.demo.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;


    /**
     * {@link IntentService} responsible for handling GCM messages.
     */
    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

        public GCMIntentService() {
            super(SENDER_ID);
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside GCMIntentService Constructor==============================");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside onRegistered Method==============================");
            Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
            displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
            ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside onUnRegistered Method==============================");
            displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
                ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
            } else {
                // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
                // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
                Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside OnMessage Method==============================");
            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
            String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside onDeletedMessages Method==============================");
            Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
            String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside onError Method==============================");
            Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
            displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
            // log message
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside onRecoverableError Method==============================");
            Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
            displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                    errorId));
            return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
        }

        /**
         * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
         */
        private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "================Inside generateNotification Method==============================");
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class);
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This code is somehow exactly the same as mine, with a minor difference in the implementation of the server, as I am using a PHP server